# Disable a dropdown based on what is defined in the Model also set Radio button to No

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Radio button, that is preselected as No in the model. But I want it to disable a dropdown menu automatically. But if you select Yes then the dropdown works. I am aware that you can do it with JQuery. But I was wondering if its possible with C# MVC.

```
        <div class="form-group dropdownSwitchContainer">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="TenantGroup">Is this a Proxy Organisation?</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="admin-form theme-primary">
                                <div class="radio-custom radio-primary mt10 mr10 pull-left">
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ProxyOrganisation, true, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                                    <label for="ProxyYes">Yes</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="radio-custom radio-primary mt10 mr10 pull-left">
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ProxyOrganisation, true, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                                    <label for="ProxyYes">No</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @{
    var emptyList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var proxiesList = new SelectList(emptyList);
    if (proxies != null)
    {
        proxiesList = new SelectList(proxies, "key", "value", 0);
    }
                    }
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="AlternativeShippingTarget">Alternative Shipping Target</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ShippingTarget, proxiesList, "Choose a target...", new { id = "targetSelect", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Choose a target..." })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ShippingTarget, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Controller**

```
`var model = new ViewModels.SocietiesCreateModel
            {
                SocietyName = string.Empty,
                CISACCode = string.Empty,
                ShippingTarget = string.Empty,
                ProxyOrganisation = false,

                PagingInfo = new ViewModels.PagingModel
                {
                    Page = page,
                    Take = take,

                    SortAscending = sortAsc,
                    SortPropertyName = sortBy
                }
            };`
```

Comment: 'I am aware that you can do it with JQuery. But I was wondering if its possible with JQuery.' errm, what? ;)

Comment: Where is `proxies` defined?  Seems to me that concerns are not being separated.  What's the difference in having the model having a property set to `'No'` and just declaring the dropdownlist as disabled on page load via jQuery?

Comment: @M12Bennett if I have the model set the property to `No` then the user is unable to make a change using the checkbox. I will try it with  JQuery as that was my initial thought, but I was just seeing if I could do something using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```html
<form action="">
    <label for="no">
        No
        <input checked id="no" name="option" type="radio" id="no"/>
    </label>
    <label for="yes">
        Yes
        <input name="option" type="radio" id="yes"/>
    </label>
    <select id="dropdown">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function toggleDropdown(){
        if ($("#no").is(":checked")) {
            $('#dropdown').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('#dropdown').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        toggleDropdown();
    });

    $('input').change(function(){
        toggleDropdown();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That is what I am after, but I was wondering if I could use C# as No would already be predefined in the Model as having a value of False. So that when the page loads the dropdown would be disabled. If not then JQuery should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with JQuery
but you could try something like this without Jquery

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="AlternativeShippingTarget">Alternative Shipping Target</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @{
            object htmlAttributes;
            if (Model.ProxyOrganisation)
            {
                htmlAttributes = new { id = "targetSelect", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Choose a target..." };
            }
            else
            {
                htmlAttributes = new { id = "targetSelect", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Choose a target...", disabled = "disabled" };
            }



            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ShippingTarget, proxiesList, "Choose a target...", htmlAttributes)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ShippingTarget, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        }
    </div>
</div>
```